# How to match images taken at different angles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have multiple images of same object taken at different angles  and has many such objects. I need to match a test image which is taken at a random angle later belongs to particular object with similar background,  by matching it with those images. The objects are light installations inside a building. Same object may be installed at different places, but backgrounds are different.

I used mean shift error, template matching from opencv and Structural Similarity Index, but with less accuracy.

How about Image Fingerprinting or SIFT/SURF

Answer (score 2):

The state of the art for such object recognition tasks are convolutional neural networks, but you will need a large labelled training set, which might rule that out. Otherwise SIFT/SURF is probably what you are looking for. They are pretty robust towards most transformations.

Comment: Is 10 images per object fine for convolution neural networks?

I tried with SIFT and ORB, its giving good results even with different angles.

Comment: 10 Images per class is very likely not enough. For an impression of the dimensions that we are talking about, look at this: [ImageNet Classification with Deep Convolutional Neural Networks](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-). They used 1.3 million images for about 1000 classes. If you can achieve your goal with SIFT, why not go for it?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but not enough rep merp.. I would suggest using feature matching along with SIFT or SRUF. You could use a homography matrix as it would help with the object being at different angles. Here is a tutorial on how to do just that: [Feature Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#py-feature-homography)

I hope this helps.